# How does one override the . operator in elixir?

Tags: macros, operator-overloading, elixir

I'm trying to override the `.` (dot) operator in elixir.  I'm able to override other binary operators (for example `defmacro a + b do` works fine for overriding `+`), but when I try to override `.` with `defmacro a . b do`, I get the following error:
    invalid syntax in defmacro a.b()

Does anyone know the correct syntax for overriding `.`?  I tried to find the code for the implementation of dot-access to maps, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Speaking as a former C++ developer,  overriding built in operators is very dangerous anyway.  Should be a last resort not a first approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` (dot) operator is a [special form](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L476).

From the [docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html):

> Special forms are the basic building blocks of Elixir, and therefore
>     cannot be overridden by the developer.